# Angular $routeProvider resolve. How to improve maintainability/readability?

Tags: angularjs

At this moment, my code look like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/alumns', {
    templateUrl: 'views/alumn.html',
    controller : "AlumnoListController",
    controllerAs : "vm",
    resolve : { alumnoDMResolve : function(AlumnosResource) {

        return AlumnosResource.refreshData().then(function (result) {
            return (result);
        });
      }
...
```

Very typical. But with this style, the whole initialization of my controllers ends in the config block of the application. Multiply this by dozens of controllers, and I'm left with too much **(in my opinion)** code inside the application config block, which is hard to read/maintain.

Is there any possibility to make this aspect better organized? 
Something like **(this obviously doesn't work)**:

```
 resolve : { alumnoDMResolve : vm.resolveFn }
```

In my opinion code relative to controller initialization would be best placed into the controller itself, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** This block:

```
$routeProvider.when('/alumns', {
    templateUrl: 'views/alumn.html',
    controller : "AlumnoListController",
    controllerAs : "vm",
    resolve : { alumnoDMResolve : function(AlumnosResource) {

        return AlumnosResource.refreshData().then(function (result) {
            return (result);
        });
      }
```

Can be written like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/alumns', {
  templateUrl: 'views/alumn.html',
  controller : "AlumnoListController",
  controllerAs : "vm",
  resolve : { alumnoDMResolve :  alumnoDMResolve }

}

function alumnoDMResolve(AlumnosResource) {

  return AlumnosResource.refreshData().then(function (result) {
    return (result);
  });
}
```

Which makes it more readable imo. 
you also have the advantage of resolving the same functions in different routes which will avoid code duplicates.

#### UPDATE

Of course it depends on what you are after.

Resolve in the route config is typically to be used for allow/reject the entering of the route at hand
or by preparing data for your view before entering the view.

If your use case is none of the above don't use resolve for routes and call your services inside your controllers.

Comment: Consuming data is done once during initialization and subsequently as many time as user interacts, so this code would be duplicated in the resolver and inside the controller. 
Your suggestion #1 definitely helps readability, but the code is still hard to maintain.

Comment: ok, typically you would want to use resolve in the router like this if you want to allow/reject the user to enter a view or if you want to prepare data for display. If that is not your use case don't use resolve